# How to show message to the user after email verification in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-routing, email-verification, laravel-request, laravel-controller

I want to display a message to the user after email verification. Getting an email to email verification after new user sign up to the website. There is a VerficationController. how I can modify to get the notification?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `override`  `verified` function like this.

```
    protected function verified(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flash('alert','You message here');
}
```

when the user will be verified this is will add a session and then where ever you redirecting you can get message from  `Session` and can show message.

**Like this:**

```
@if(Session::has('alert'))
  <p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">
    {{ Session::get('alert') }}
  </p>
@endif
```